# How can i create a function that takes un-assigned variable in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a function that takes a variable whether it was set or not,

like the function isset()

```
//we have this array
$array  = array();
isset($array["test"]);//this one is valid 
myFunc($array["test"]);//this one is not valid
```

how can i let my function take not set variables?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It sounds like a flaw in the program's design, to be honest. What's wrong with `isset()`?

Comment: you want to check if variable is set and its not null ?

Comment: `isset()` is technically a language construct, rather than a function, so the standard rules don't apply to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the argument as a reference
http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

```
function myFunc(&$val)
{
    return isset($val);
}

var_dump(myFunc($undefined));
```

Comment: The reference to `$undefined`, if not set, would presumably error if the PHP's error reporting settings were set to a strict enough level

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Perhaps I'm wrong. I had assumed that, if strict error reporting was on, a reference to a variable that is not set, would error. Perhaps because it's being passed to a function the rules are different.

Comment: @Laxus: it doesn't trigger an error, but passing by reference that which is undefined issues a warning. Even an array that is the return value of a function cannot be passed by reference without a warning being thrown (eg: `end(explode('_',get_class($foo_bar_Instance)));` -> spits warning: end expects array reference)

Answer (score 1):

It's common to come across this problem if you're using `$_GET` and friends, because you can't rely on a given field being passed into your program.

I use a utility class for this, so I can avoid errors with unset vars and also populate defaults into them.

```
<?php
function defArrayElem(&$array, $key, $default=null) {
    if(!isset($array[$key])) {$array[$key]=$default;}
}

//repeat for all the $_GET/$_POST vars you expect...
defArrayElem($_GET,'keyname','default-value');
?>
```

Now you don't need to worry about checking if they're set or not.

Comment: I agree. If you want to see a more advanced example, see https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb3/blob/master/phpBB/includes/functions.php#L63

Comment: @Laxus - in fact the version we use is indeed more complex than this (we have a whole class to deal with it), but I posted a one-line function to demonstrate the point, rather than posting the whole class, which would have been a bit overkill for answering the question.